# Linux Mint x64: Qt 5.3.1 plugin deployment: incompatible qt library

Tags: c++, linux, qt, deployment, cmake

Using CMake to build both an app and plugin for it. Everything works fine on developer's PC, but on remote clean Linux Mint x64 installation there is an error:

> plugin uses incompatible qt library Qt 5.3.1 [release]

Plugin and Application was build in release mode (actually I have tryed different combinations, with no luck)

I saw one guy here already asked about similar issue on Windows, but his question not answered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by exporting QML2_IMPORT_PATH and QT_PLUGIN_PATH, and copy dependebncies of Qt platform plugins (xcb)